# How can i use $ref in json-schema with vue-json-schema-form?

Tags: vue.js, jsonschema, json-ref

I am trying to generate a form which can have multiple recursive fields. I have used https://codepen.io/crickford/pen/ZmJqwd this demo (I am not using any custom component). Whenever i am using **"$ref"** it ignores it. I am using vue-json-schema-form. Here is the link of github https://github.com/crickford/vue-json-schema-form.
Even if i use "$ref":"#" it's not working.

My Json-schema is valid. Even if i replace the following schema in codepen i don't get expected result, where as it is giving me proper output by editing **schema** property of the **source** in this link http://www.alpacajs.org/docs/api/recursive-references.html

I don't know where am I mistaking !! At least in codepen attached schema code should work.
Kindly guide me or share working demo fiddle with me. Thanks in advance.

Here is my schema:

```
   {
    "type": "object",
    "title": "",
    "properties": {
        "Namespace": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "Namespace ",
            "attrs": {
                "placeholder": "Namespace",
                "title": "Please enter Namespace"
            }
        },
        "Name": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "Display Name : ",
            "attrs": {
                "placeholder": "Display Name",
                "title": "Please enter Display name"
            }
        },
        "SubSteps": {
            "type": "array",
            "title": "SubSteps",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "title": "Sub step",
                "$ref": "#/definitions/SubSteps"
            }
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "SubSteps": {
            "type": "object",
            "title": "SubStep item",
            "properties": {
                "Namespace": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "title": "Namespace ",
                    "attrs": {
                        "placeholder": "Namespace",
                        "title": "Please enter Namespace"
                    }
                },
                "Name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "title": "Display Name : ",
                    "attrs": {
                        "placeholder": "Display Name",
                        "title": "Please enter Display name"
                    }
                },
                "SubSteps": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "title": "SubSteps",
                    "items": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "title": "Sub step",
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/SubSteps"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "Name"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Form generation with JSON Schema is not standardised. Each library will "do their own thing"(tm). For vue-json-schema-form, there's no mention of `$ref` in the codebase, and therefore I can only assume it's not supported.

Comment: Given you've left an issue on the associated github repo, you might want to delete your question here. Your schema is correct as far as JSON Schema validation goes.

Comment: Are there other ways to use json-schema with refs OR json to generate dynamic form in vue js?

Comment: Sure, you can write your own code to do it. Or you could use an alternate library which doesn't have the vue interfaces. It really depends what you need.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the library in question supports the use of `$ref`. Therefore you would have to submit an issue and / or pull request to add the functionality you want.